# IOS Image view Image not getting assigned correctly if not wrapped in an object

Tags: ios, media

I solved my problem now, i would just be curious about **WHY** this was happening.
I have an image view, and i want to assign an image from camera to it. So i call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(!image) image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    self.imageView.image = image;

}
```

Which doesn't work at all. But when i change it to the following:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(!image) image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.object.image = image;
    self.imageView.image = self.object.image;

}
```

It works like charm, the image gets assigned correctly. Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you not declaring `image` correctly. It you do the following you should not need the self.object line:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
if(!image) image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

self.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: I tried this as well when solving the problem, interesting enough, it doesn't change then. Also i did @synthesize image; in my above function. So this can not be the reason..

Comment: what do you mean it does not change? Can you try putting it in the completion block of dismissViewController?

Comment: By it doesnt change i mean the problem persists. What sense would it make to put it in the dismissViewController?

Comment: And as i stated above,  i already solved my problem. I am just corious to find out what made the difference!

Comment: did u meant that your image is rotated?